# Can you switch tenses when starting a new paragraph?

Tags: grammar

For example, explaining something that happened in the past, then returning to the current scene.

> Here is the example put into action:

They talked about various things. They rode out together, but stopped at a tavern for a moment. They tossed stones at a pond. They sung a few songs. Blah, blah blah...

Now they are here, and preparing for the fight. He says whatever, she says whatever, and their swords clash.  He twirls for some reason. It is all to further the example.

Comment: What makes you think you can't switch tenses in the *same* paragraph—or even the same *sentence*? Is the question related to a new paragraph specifically, or just switching tenses in general? Also, what do you mean by switching tenses? Are you talking about the general tense used throughout a paragraph, or about any kind for verb change at all?

Comment: @Jason Bassford A new paragraph. As I've been taught, you aren't meant to switch tenses in the same sentence...or paragraph. And yes, I mean the general tense.

Comment: Just to be clear, here's a common form of a single sentence where verb tenses are switched: *Because of the rain, if the car **was** not parked in the garage last night, then it **is** wet now.* But it looks like what you're discussing is more a matter of narrative style than specific grammar.

Comment: Let's say, hypothetically, that one can't change tenses when starting a new paragraph: that would mean every paragraph in the entire document would have to be in the same tense - does that seem at all reasonable to you?

Comment: I suspect this actually belongs more at [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) than here, where overall stylistic advice is on topic. It's much less a question of can you, but of how it would affect the writing if you did.

Answer (score 0):

After I had read this question, I considered it, and now I answer it by asserting that, even in one sentence, you will find that tenses may be mixed. What is true for a sentence in this respect is also true for paragraphs.